# It's catching up with you but good

Tags: word-usage, metaphors

The following line is taken from Sin City 2005,

> Bad guy: John Hartigan, Mr. "Law and Order", Mr. "By-The-Book", Mr.
>   High and Mighty.
>   I got to give you credit. Being such a straight arrow
>   for so damn many years without it catching up with you. It's catching up with you now, friend of mine. It's catching up with you **but
>   good**.

Is **but** here an adverb, meaning 'only'? And is **good** here also an adverb, meaning 'well'?

I think **straight arrow** is a metaphor. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*But good* is idiomatic. It means *thoroughly*.

*Straight arrow* is indeed a metaphor, meaning someone who is good and law-abiding.

Comment: Oops, I didn't expect that's an idiom..

Answer (score 1):

"But" here means something like "except". It's catching up to you, except not just in the normal manner, but even more so. Like if you do something or something is done "good", either a lot of it is done or it's done really well. It is not quite idiomatic because "but good" isn't quite a fixed expression yet, but the strategy the speaker uses isn't that uncommon.

Comment: Do you mean "exceptionally good"?

Comment: No, I really mean 'except'. But the concept it gets across in the end is one of the 'catching up' being exceptionally good.